# 'Starting LLDB server' when debugging c++ in Android studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, lldb

I want to debug c++ module in Android Studio.
I create a project with c++ support in android studio.

When i debug, this is what i get.
[image]

'Starting LLDB server' will never stop. If I stop debugging, its still there. If I exit android studio, i get warning about running background process. I already installed LLDB in SDK manager. I have enable debugging in my device.

What should I do?

Comment: Finally got it working. On my samsung s4, i have to manually attach the debugger. lldb works fine on emulator. probably its samsung s4 thing.

Comment: Not working on emulator for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 3.5 I encounter similar issue with LLDB debugger - where "Starting LLDB server" process hangs forever, no debugging process is started. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57770074/565525).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem today all of a sudden Android Studio 3.5.3. What fixed it for me was to uninstall & reinstall `Android SDK Platform Tools` and `LLDB`.

This was the exact steps I followed:

1. Open Android Studio
   -> Preferences
   -> Appearance & Behavior
   -> System Settings
   -> Android SDK
   -> SDK Tools tab
2. Uncheck `LLDB` and `Android SDK Platform-Tools`
3. Click `Apply` & let `sdkmanager` uninstall those items.
4. Re-Check `LLDB` (I'm using 3.1) and `Android SDK Platform-Tools` (I'm using 29.0.5)
5. Click `Apply` & let `sdkmanager` install those items
6. Quit Android Studio & any running emulators
7. Restart Android Studio

After that, running the debugger no longer hangs at `Starting LLDB Server` for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I realized it was caused by using ADB over WiFi.

But when I connected the phone via USB cable and tried to start debugging this way, it was still stuck.

**I had to disable the WiFi on the phone** and then it started working immediately.