# IDE waiting for debugger for a long time

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio version is 3.5 .I can't debug app in android studio. 
I got the following message

```
Starting LLDB server: /data/data/com.example.core.app/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh /data/data/com.example.core.app/lldb unix-abstract /com.example.core.app-0 platform-1568620766570.sock "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"
Failed to connect port
```

I tried changing phone and cable.

I have lldb installed.

I have also debug enabled

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

I have also tried restarting adb with following command

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

My operating system ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you used the emulator before? If yes, wipe emulator data. Then go to Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project.

Comment: No , I am using real device  always

Comment: See if you get the same problem with an emulator, and update your question with results. This would help figure out if it's something with your device or cable.

Comment: you may look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172427/android-studio-1-4-cannot-launch-debug-server/57770074#57770074

Answer (score 0):

If you have a doubt about your cable try connect your device over Wifi.
 using adb->

open cmd.

```
adb tcpip 5555

adb connect <your device IP address>:5555
```